# Cannot get intelrealsense to compile from source on a Raspi4 8GB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, realsense

Hello I have been following this guide
https://github.com/datasith/Ai_Demos_RPi/wiki/Raspberry-Pi-4-and-Intel-RealSense-D435

In an attempt to get the librealsense sdk to compile from source on my raspberry pi4 8gb; however I am getting the following error during compilation

```bash
In file included from /home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/context-libusb.h:10,
                 from /home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/context-libusb.cpp:4:
/home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/libusb.h:10:82: error: extended character ‘ is not valid in an identifier
   10 | /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h:736:4: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ▒▒▒dev_capability_data’ [-Wpedantic]
      |                                                                                  ^
/home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/libusb.h:10:82: error: extended character ’ is not valid in an identifier
/home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/libusb.h:13:82: error: extended character ‘ is not valid in an identifier
   13 | /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h:767:4: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ▒▒▒dev_capability’ [-Wpedantic]
      |                                                                                  ^
/home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/libusb.h:13:82: error: extended character ’ is not valid in an identifier
/home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/libusb.h:18:83: error: extended character ‘ is not valid in an identifier
   18 | /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h:1260:4: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ▒▒▒iso_packet_desc’ [-Wpedantic]
      |                                                                                   ^
/home/yalt/librealsense/src/libusb/libusb.h:18:83: error: extended character ’ is not valid in an identifier
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/realsense2.dir/build.make:1200: CMakeFiles/realsense2.dir/src/libusb/context-libusb.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1103: CMakeFiles/realsense2.dir/all] Error 2
```

Im assuming it has something to do with my udev rules, as that is the only part of the installation process where libusb is mentioned previous, but aside from that I am lost

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug related to the new GCC

It was fixed here:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/pull/10818